# animating an object after fling gesutre

Tags: java, android

I have a basic object that responds to flings on the screen. my problem i am not sure how to animate the image I am flinging on the screen. basically I have a static image of a football, that I want to animate as its flung across the screen. here is a snippet of my code where I define my image to fling:

```
public PlayAreaView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            translate = new Matrix();
            gestures = new GestureDetector(FGKick.this,
                    new GestureListener(this));

            football = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.fgball);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you may want to look at either Tween or Frame Animation in the API.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Also replica island http://code.google.com/p/replicaisland/ maybe be helpful. It's a good resource (with source) for doing various animations using XML to define the animations.

Comment: Excellent. I will look into that and let you know how I make out.